# How to create php page that have dynamic number of input boxes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So i try to create a page that have only one input box. We will read a data of QR code which have a new line at the end. And if i read the qr it should open anohter input box and write the next QR code into this and so on...

And it the end of the page there will be a "Send" button which sends the datas into mysql.

Any idea?

Thats what I have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

?>
<head>
</head>
<body >

<form name="form" action="send.php" method="post">
<div style="top: 40%; left: 40%; position: absolute;">
QR: <input type="text" name="QR"><br>

<input type="submit" class ="button" value="SEND!" >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 1**

After the page loads in and i click into the box it's creats a new blank box.
And it should create the new box after enter. And after this at all, how can I get the values of all the boxes? :)
Thanks for help!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

?>
<head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
  //suppose you are reading QR code in below function

  $(".QR").click(function(){
    // QR code is like below
    var qrCode = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var lastInput = $('.QR:last');
    lastInput.val(qrCode);
    //add input after last input box
    lastInput.after('<br><input type="text" class="QR"><br>');
    var qrCode="";
  });

  // submit all QR values
  $('form.form').submit(function(){
    //you can read all value and append in a variable 
    var values= "";
    $('input.name').each(function(){
       values += $(this).val();
    });
  });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <input type="text" class="QR" id="input">
    <br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**
There is only one problem, that is when i load the page and the first write in is a blank cell every time. :(
And a quetion: How can I send the `values` to the `send.php` which will contains a `php` and that will the datas to the mysql.

Now i have this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

?>
<head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
  //suppose you are reading QR code in below function

  $(".QR").keyup(function(event){
    // QR code is like below
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
    var qrCode = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var lastInput = $('.QR:last');
    lastInput.val(qrCode);
    //add input after last input box
    lastInput.after('<br><input type="text" class="QR"><br>');
    document.getElementById("input").value="";
    }
  });

  // submit all QR values
  $('form.form').submit(function(){
    //you can read all value and append in a variable 
    var values= "";
    $('input.name').each(function(){
       values += $(this).val();
    });
  });

});
    </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
//Enterre, nem lép tovább:
      function stopRKey(evt) { 
        var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
        var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
        if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
      } 

      document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 

</script>
</head>
<body >
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="QR" id="input">
    <button type="submit" formaction="send.php" >Feltöltés!</button>
  </form>  

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried anything from your side first?

Comment: I've just create a page with an input box. But in my opinion it should use ajax and i'm not really know anything about it. To sum up i didnt make anything which make sense.

Comment: Can you share your page code having single input box, send button and QR code read functionlity, so that we can help you better?

Comment: are you using any ajax call to read QR code ? can you pls share that code also.

Comment: The QR code contains some text, and it has set that the computer recognize the QR reader  as another keyboard and thats why I dont really need any code to handle it

Comment: As you said, you want to add another input box after reading QR code. for this, we need to know the event triggered after QR read and on this particular event you can add a input box.

Comment: I dont have any trigger. At the end of QR there is an enter. And it should open another input box. But thats what I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : Use class="QR" instead of name attribute for input box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

?>
<head>
</head>
<body >

<form name="form" action="send.php" method="post">
<div style="top: 40%; left: 40%; position: absolute;">
QR: <input type="text" class="QR"><br>

<input type="submit" class ="button" value="SEND!" >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  //suppose you are reading QR code in below function

  $('.QR').click(function(){
    // QR code is like below
    var qrCode = "qr code";
    var lastInput = $('.QR:last');
    lastInput.val(qrCode);
    //add input after last input box
    lastInput.after('<input type="text" class="QR"><br>');
  });

  // submit all QR values
  $('form.form').submit(function(){
    //you can read all value and append in a variable 
    var values= "";
    $('input.name').each(function(){
       values += $(this).val();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Should JQuery go into send.php or into the form?

Comment: It should be in the `<head>` with `<script>` tag, like this `<head><script>  your jquery code </script></head>`

Comment: Its nearly what i have to have. I edited the descr. Can u help me a liltle bit more,

Comment: You can get comma seperated values of all text boxes when you submit the form as mentioned in my answer, just replace this code `values += $(this).val() + ",";`

Comment: Ahw thanks, and can you help me that not for the click event, but the "enter keypress" make the new cell?

Comment: for key press your can replace `click` with `keyup` event. Are you trying to read for any particular key press?

Comment: The function should called when there is an enter keyperess

Comment: But i can handle it:<blink>
  $(".QR").keyup(function(event){
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {}</blink>

Comment: Edited the dscrptn. Can you help a little bit more?
And can you suggest some book to learn ajax/jquery?

Comment: With this I can send the value of the "values" to the send.php?

Comment: You can send data with Ajax cal and read it in your application. Check this example, where `data` attribute set with string data - https://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

to add a new input to a form field you can use below code :

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'input',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'bar'
}).appendTo('form');
```

when ever you need to add a new input you can call a function and inside the function use the above code to add input to form. Please use some kind of incremental number to make the id and name unique

Comment: It needs ajax, doesnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this. In this I have HTML code which has a `form` with only one `input tag` first, one `button` to add more fields, one `submit button`:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<input type="text" name="value[]"><button class="add_field_button">+</button></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="SEND">
</form>
```

jQuery to add or `append` more `input` fields:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="value[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

PHP script to see posted form values:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);   
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I wil try it. And sorry I'm new at SO.

Comment: Ofc i wiill mark it. But I think i can understand your code, and i should paste it into body and the first row into head right? And should i change anythyng?  Or i should paste it into the form?